# How RabbitMQ handle if queue message bytes length large than x-max-length-bytes?

Tags: rabbitmq

I had declare a queue like below:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-max-length-bytes", 2 * 1024 * 1024);  // Max length is 2G
channel.queueDeclare("queueName", true, false, false, args);
```

When the queue messages count bytes is large than 2G, It will auto remove the message on the head of the queue.
But what I expected is That it reject produce the last message and return exception to the producer.
How can I get it?

Comment: "return exception" do you mean the exception to the producer?

Comment: yes, you are right. my english is a little bad. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround is check the queue size before send your message using the [HTTP API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html).

For example if you have a queue called: `myqueuetest` with max size = 20.

Before send the message you can call the HTTP API in this way:
http://localhost:15672/api/queues/

the result is a `JSON` like this:

```
  "message_bytes":10,
  "message_bytes_ready":10,
  "message_bytes_unacknowledged":0,
  "message_bytes_ram":10,
  "message_bytes_persistent":0,
..
  "name":"myqueuetest",
  "vhost":"test",
  "durable":true,
  "auto_delete":false,
  "arguments":{
     "x-max-length-bytes":20
  },
```

then you cloud read the `message_bytes` field before send your message and then decide if send or not.

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

1. This workaround could kill your application performance
2. This workaround is not safe if you have multi-threading/more publisher
3. This workaround is not a very "best practise"

Just try to see if it is ok for your application.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution. But with HTTP request before per message send may affect efficiency. If this can config at RabbitMQ may better. Does RabbitMQ support config like this?

Comment: We can cache the `message_bytes ` in memory for better performance. But it will become more complex. So if RabbitMQ has configuration may be better.

Comment: excuse me @tangjiujun but config for what? As I wrote this can kill the performance. As wrote old_sound feel free to open an issue. I think could be an good feature for RMQ.

Comment: Forgive my lazy, Your answer meet my need. Thanks. But I hope I can achieve the same effect through the RabbitMQ configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

As explained on the official docs:

> Messages will be dropped or dead-lettered from the front of the queue to make room for new messages once the limit is reached.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html

If you think RabbitMQ should drop messages form the end of the queue, feel free to open an issue here so we can discuss about it https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues

Comment: This is the only strategy? Is there a strategy that prevent the producer continue produce message once the limit is reached.

Comment: Right now this is the only strategy. Feel free to open an issue on github